# android get an integer from a spinner similar to that of the method used for strings

Tags: java, android, xml, integer, spinner

In two parts of my app I have spinners.  One spinner provides a set of strings, and the one I'm currently working on is supposed to allow the user to select a preset number (10, 25, 50, 100) of questions to take a practice test with that many questions.

I figured it'd be a simple copy/paste of the current spinner that works, while just changing the `toString();` to `toInteger();` but it doesn't seem to be the case.  As I looked up how to retrieve an integer from a spinner, it looks significantly different than how I implemented my spinner of Strings.  I know there's more than one way to do most things, but I'm curious if there's a direct translation from strings to integers when using spinners?

Basically, how do I use the same setup to achieve a spinner for integers?

Java Method:

```
    //Get spinner selection
    final Spinner userInputSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.feedbackSpinner);
    String TYPE = userInputSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

XML Spinner:

```
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/feedbackSpinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/feedbackType"
        android:entries="@array/feedbackChoice"/>
```

Arrays XML:

```
<!--ARRAY FOR FEEDBACK SPINNER-->
<string-array name="feedbackChoice">
    <item>@string/feedbackCompliment</item>
    <item>@string/feedbackSuggestion</item>
    <item>@string/feedbackWrong</item>
    <item>@string/feedbackIssue</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: I'm confused. Are you having trouble setting the integers in the spinner, getting the item that was selected, or something else? Either way, I don't see your code that would even attempt to do either.

Comment: You can retrieve the string `s` and call `int number = Integer.parseInt(s)`.

Comment: @codeMagic This is the code I use for the String spinner.  I'm curious how I'd go about implementing pretty much the same code (if possible) but for integers.  I attempted to do so (replacing the seemingly necessary components from strings to ints) and creating an array of ints to choose from, but it didn't work.

Comment: Then that's the part you should show us. Otherwise, it's really difficult to know what part of your attempt with `int`s didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem, I think you need a conversion from string to int.
Try that :

Java Method:

```
//Get spinner selection
final Spinner userInputSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerInt);
int TYPE = Integer.parseInt(userInputSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

XML Spinner:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerInt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/intChoice"/>
```

Arrays XML:

```
<string-array name="intChoice">
    <item>10</item>
    <item>25</item>
    <item>50</item>
    <item>100</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: Ah, got it.  Yeah it wasn't quite as direct as I had thought.  I didn't know anything about the parsing.  Thanks @JavaJade!